# Is there a python equivalent to the bash function "export"?

Tags: python, bash

I am attempting to translate a bash script into python code and am currently hung up on the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local:/usr/lib
```

I cannot figure out what this line is doing and subsequently can't find a python equivalent, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: setting up the environment path.

Comment: @AvinashRaj so would something like: os.environ(['/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local:/usr/lib']) work?